# Leaks in UIPasteboard objects

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, instruments, memory-leaks

I see a lot of leaks in several UIPasteboard objects. Until today, I never heard of this class and (obviously) didn't use one myself in the program. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Instruments Screenshot]

What can I do to get rid of these leaks? Am I even looking at this problem correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this myself, but I believe there is such a guide to help with this. Is this what your looking for? http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial

Comment: The first thing you can do is paste the code you use regarding the pasteboars so we can look at how it may be leaking.

Comment: @Zigglzworth: As I mentioned in the question, I have not used pasteboards in the code so I really do not know what to paste here.

Comment: Something in your code must be using UIPastBoards. Are you using 3rd party code of any kind?

Comment: @Zigglzworth: You are so right! I was using the openUDID package and it leaks. https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/blob/master/OpenUDID.m That's where the code is. Do you want me to accept your other answer?

Comment: @Ravi: Don't accept his other answer, it would be misleading to anyone else who comes across this. He should post a separate answer instead instructing you to look at 3rd-party code, and you can accept that one.

Comment: @Ravi, I added another answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to check if the problem is a UIPasteBoard instance in any 3rd party code used.

Comment: I had a string of leaked objects in UIPasteboard class inside the OpenUDID library. Hope this would be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Without a stack trace, you can't do a whole lot.

UIPasteboard is used for implementing copy&paste. On the desktop it's also used for drag&drop. Besides these two tasks, I'm not really sure what else people commonly use it for, but it is a way to send snippets of data between apps (assuming both apps know to look at the pasteboard).

Comment: My code does not perform any copy/paste actions. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Ravi: Figure out why you aren't getting a stack trace in Instruments. You may need to turn on malloc stack logging.

Comment: I have updated the image to reflect stack trace. Any thoughts? I'm now pretty sure its from OpenUDID. Here's the code: https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/blob/master/OpenUDID.m

Comment: Sure :) but note a comment regarding the answer that it was indeed 3rd party code

Answer (score -1):

If this is not an application pasteboard that you have set than it is a system pasteboard so you will need to access the generalPasteBoard than get all its items and all the types for those items and set their string and data values to nil.

```
generalpasteboard UIPasteBoard *pb = [UIPasteboard pasteBoardWithName:UIPasteboardNameGeneral];
for (UIPasteBoardItem *pbItem in [pb items]) {

      for (NSString pbType in [pbItem pasteboardTypes]) {
       [pbItem setData:nil forPasteboardType:pbType];
       [pbItem setValue:nil forPasteboardType:pbType];
      }
}
```

try putting this at the beginning of your application.... Still its strange that the general pasteboard is leaking... By the way, it may also be the find pasteboard UIPasteboardNameFind (also a system pasteboard)

Note that this is for finding out if it is the general pasteboard not using in the final distributed app. Also make sure to check if the problem is a UIPastBoard instance in any 3rd party code used.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a *terrible* idea. Adding UIPasteboard access where there is none, and completely blowing away the user's clipboard, for absolutely no expected gain. Ravi, please don't do this.

Comment: @Kevin : It's not for using in the actual app. It's for finding out if the leak is caused by the general pasteboard.